# Can a file/message contain its own HMAC?

Tags: security, hmac

I am doing a computer security project and am trying to encrypt key-value pairs that are stored in an untrusted database. I wanted to protect the value with an HMAC, in addition to encrypting the content. I was wondering how HMACs are used in practice--do you append the HMAC to the original file/message or store the HMAC separately from the file/message?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on Crypto.SE, at best.

Comment: Both options are valid, but please make sure that you include the IV used for encryption/decryption in the MAC calculation. Or use an authenticated mode such as GCM. It's probably easiest to concat IV, ciphertext and authentication tag as the IV and authentication tag sizes are known in advance.